# how to calculate the total charge for a specific fragment in a molecule using NBO analysis with Gaussian?

Tags: density-functional-theory, gaussian

hi my molecule is devided into 5 fragment, I want to perform an NBO analysis and calculate the total charge of each fragment instead of doing it by hand (by summing atomic charges) , is there a way to do that in gaussian ?

I tried to use the fragment key word in gaussian but I got the following error

```
%chk=nbo.chk
# 6-31g(d) guess=(only,fragment=5) pop=nbo pbe1pbe
..

..
..
```

error:

```
 Storage needed:      9404 in NPA,      7373 in NBO (  33548014 available)

 Subroutine NAOANL could not find a S-type core orbital on atom  C    1.
 ICORE :  1  0  0  0     M :  1     LA :  1
 Error
 Error termination via Lnk1e in C:\G09W\l607.exe at Wed Sep 20 15:41:14 2023.
 Job cpu time:  0 days  0 hours  1 minutes 41.0 seconds.
 File lengths (MBytes):  RWF=     82 Int=      0 D2E=      0 Chk=     12 Scr=      1
```